# When building links for a multi-language website, should they point directly to the country content, or to the main "choose your language" page?

Tags: seo, backlinks, multilingual

I have a multi-language website with subfolders for each language.

Germany:
`https://example.com/de/`

French:
`https://example.com/fr/`

How do I handle the backlink building?

For Germany:

Should I link to the main root `www.example.com` or to the subfolder `www.example.com/de/`?

Comment: Link building usually involves links to many pages, not just to the home page.   You may need to re-think your link building strategy all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link to whatever is the most relevant. If you're posting german content somewhere then it would make sense for the backlink to point to the german version of the website.

Remember user experience - if a user is reading content in German and they click on a link to the author's page, they would expect the language to remain the same.

Don't get too hung up with sending link juice to your root domain. Links to subfolders still benefit the root domain and the value in building language-specific links back to your multilingual pages will be far more worthwhile.